# Do we have $End(V \otimes V) = End(V) \otimes End(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Do we have $End(V \otimes V) = End(V) \otimes End(V)$? Any help will be greatly apprciated!

Comment: Hint: There is a simple natural map from $End(V)\otimes End(V)$ to $End(V\otimes V)$. Verify that this map is injective and then compare dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hint:

Prove that $\mathrm{End}(V) \simeq V^\ast \otimes V$.

Also prove that $(V \otimes V)^\ast \simeq V^\ast \otimes V^\ast$.