# Example for $\text {End}(V \otimes W) $ not isomorphic to $\text{End}(V) \otimes \text{End}(W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, tensor-products

A couple of posts relate to this topic and indicate that when the spaces are finite dimensional there is a canonical isomorphism, while in the infinite dimensional case there is only an injection $\mathrm{End}(V) \otimes \mathrm{End}(W) \to \mathrm{End}(V \otimes W)$.

[Do we have $End(V \otimes V) = End(V) \otimes End(V)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540764/do-we-have-endv-otimes-v-endv-otimes-endv)

[Operators on a Tensor Product Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327123/operators-on-a-tensor-product-space)

https://mathoverflow.net/q/72013

So, is there an example that demonstrates this ?

I considered infinite dimensional spaces over the reals with dimension $c$ and concluded that

1. With $\dim(V) = \dim(W) = c$
2. $\dim (\text{End} (V)) = c^c$; so $\dim (\text{End} (V) \otimes \text{End}(W)) = c^c.c^c = c^c$;
3. $\dim (V \otimes W) = c.c = c$
4. $\dim(\text {End}(V \otimes W) ) = c^c = \dim (\text{End} (V) \otimes \text{End}(W))$

So, if my (cardinal) arithmetic is correct they are isomorphic in this case.

---

In response to the first two comments, I see that the fact that the given canonical injection  is not an isomorphism doesn't preclude the spaces being isomorphic. So my question is are they *always* isomorphic in the infinite dimensional case or is there an example to show they are not ?

Comment: Imprecise language, I guess. What is meant is that the obvious map $\operatorname{End}(V) \otimes \operatorname{End} (W) \to \operatorname{End} (V \otimes W)$ is only an isomorphism in the finite-dimensional case, not that there can't be an abstract isomorphism between these space in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: What is your question exactly? the two are isomorphic, but not _canonically so_ (in the sense that the canonical injection is not onto).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - Thanks, see the added last paragraph.

Comment: @DanielFischer  - Thanks, see the added last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the axiom of choice. I don't know what weirdness may happen otherwise here.

Let's suppose that $\kappa = \dim V \leqslant \lambda = \dim W$, and $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal.

If $\kappa = 0$, then $\operatorname{End} (V\otimes W) = \operatorname{End} \{0\} = \{0\} = (\operatorname{End} \{0\}) \otimes (\operatorname{End} W)$. And if $\kappa > 0$, then we have

$$\dim (V \otimes W) = \kappa\cdot \lambda = \lambda = \dim W,$$

so it follows that $V \otimes W \cong W$, and consequently

$$\operatorname{End} (V \otimes W) \cong \operatorname{End} W.$$

Thus, with the canonical injection $(\operatorname{End} V) \otimes (\operatorname{End} W) \to \operatorname{End} (V \otimes W)$ we deduce

$$\dim (\operatorname{End} W) \leqslant \dim \bigl((\operatorname{End} V) \otimes (\operatorname{End} W)\bigr) \leqslant \dim \operatorname{End} (V \otimes W) = \dim (\operatorname{End} W),$$

whence there always is an abstract isomorphism between $(\operatorname{End} V) \otimes (\operatorname{End} W)$ and $\operatorname{End} (V \otimes W)$, whatever the dimensions of the spaces. But when both spaces are infinite-dimensional, the canonical map is not an isomorphism, and that's what people are interested in.